# Dask - How to concatenate Series into a DataFrame with apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

How do I return multiple values from a function applied on a Dask Series?
I am trying to return a series from each iteration of `dask.Series.apply` and for the final result to be a `dask.DataFrame`.

The following code tells me that the meta is wrong. The all-pandas version however works. What's wrong here?

**Update:** I think that I am not specifying the meta/schema correctly. How do I do it correctly?
Now it works when I drop the meta argument. However, it raises a warning. I would like to use dask "correctly".

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

def transformMyCol(x):
    #Minimal Example Function
    return(pd.Series(['Tom - ' + str(x),'Deskflip - ' + str(x / 8),'']))

#
## Pandas Version - Works as expected.
#
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']], columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
pandas_df.target.apply(transformMyCol,1)

#
## Dask Version (second attempt) - Raises a warning
#
df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=10)

unpacked = df.target.apply(transformMyCol)
unpacked.head()

#
## Dask Version (first attempt) - Raises an exception 
#
df = dd.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=10)

unpacked_dask_schema = {"name" : str, "action" : str, "comments" : str}

unpacked = df.target.apply(transformMyCol, meta=unpacked_dask_schema)
unpacked.head()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 3693, in apply_and_enforce
    raise ValueError("The columns in the computed data do not match"
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
```

I have also trued the following and it also does not work.

```
meta_df = pd.DataFrame(dtype='str',columns=list(unpacked_dask_schema.keys()))


unpacked = df.FILEDATA.apply(transformMyCol, meta=meta_df)
unpacked.head()
```

Same error:

```
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 3693, in apply_and_enforce
    raise ValueError("The columns in the computed data do not match"
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
```

Comment: Hi power, please produce a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular a small sample of df will be great.

Comment: @user32185 Done.

Comment: @user32185 To clarify: The first piece of code is now an MCVE that raises the exception described.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this apply is supposed to do. Do you have an example of it working with pandas? Or could you post the output you are trying to get?

Comment: @user32185 Done. I have also made the `transformMyCol()` a little bit less minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the problem is you're not specifying the meta correctly; more specifically and as the error message says, the metadata columns (`"name", "action", "comments"`) do not match the columns in the computed data (`0, 1, 2`). You should either:

1. Change the metadata columns to 0, 1, 2:

```
   unpacked_dask_schema = dict.fromkeys(range(3), str)
   df.target.apply(transformMyCol, meta=unpacked_dask_schema)
```

or

2. Change `transformMyCol` to use the named columns:

```
    def transformMyCol(x):
        return pd.Series({
            'name': 'Tom - ' + str(x), 
            'action': 'Deskflip - ' + str(x / 8), 
            'comments': '',
        }))
```